# How to set axis minimum and maximum in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

Below is my code, Still i see Y-AXIS plotting starts from 0. do help..

```
YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setAxisMaxValue(1500f);
leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(1200f); 
leftAxis.setStartAtZero(false);
```

Thanks
amit

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `axis.setStartAtZero(false)` before the other two calls and call `chart.invalidate()` afterwards.

Comment: Are you calling invalidate afterwards?

Comment: yes..after setting x-Axis, i am calling invalidate()